# Load module in another custom module joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have a module with simple pop-up that asks for authorization.
Also I have a authorization module called slogin that was included via `<jdoc:include ..`  in the header of the website in the template. 
So in my module that requires slogin system, I'm unable to do it via jdoc. 
I tried also to import this module

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_slogin');
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, $attribs);
```

But I only got an ajax-loader. Any suggestions?

Comment: I use slogin as well, have you tried something like this ?
`code`
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('slogin_auth');
$plugins = array();
$dispatcher->trigger('onCreateSloginLink', array(&$plugins, $callbackUrl));
`code`
Then a simple loop on $plugins & you can easily include your social login buttons from that module

Comment: Better formatted @ https://snipt.net/raw/9adfee10d1c9624e7060248e4792d3f8/?nice